# Replace \r\n to " "

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I want to replace `\r\n` in my string with blank space. 
It's a Windows mobile application Compact Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\r\n"," ");
```